# Trusting additional CAs in iOS application

Tags: ios, react-native, ssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I'm basically looking for a way, in an iOS app I'm developing, to achieve the same thing as [this on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingAdditionalCas).

I need to somehow embed my CA cert in the iOS app and then configure it to trust that CA in addition to the system certificates.

Is this possible without writing native code?

I'm using Expo so ideally I'd like an easy way via `Info.plist` or something like that if possible.

I haven't really tried anything yet. I did for Android and it works, just can't figure out how to do the same thing on iOS.

Comment: Trust it to do *what* exactly? A certificate is just data, and an application is just software. So in principle you can have it do anything (presuming that Apple will OK the code, it's the big greatest company on earth and all the universe after all). Or do you need it for some specific function, and if yes, do you need the system to accomplish that goal?

Comment: Basically I have an API server I need my iOS/Android app to talk to, but that server doesn't have a public domain and its IP is unknown before deployment. So, what I'm doing right now is having a local CA cert that creates SSL certs for this server at runtime.

However, in order for me to do a `fetch('https://<server_ip>/some/endpoing')` request I need the SSL validation to pass. Without any changes to my iOS/Android client applications, these requests will fail.

However, for Android, I got it working by adding my own CA as a "trust anchor". I want to know how to achieve the same for iOS.

Comment: And I also don't want to bypass SSL validation, because that would be unsafe. I just need my client apps to validate SSL certificates against this extra CA (on top of the system CAs and normal validation).